# Getting error Failed to minify the code from this file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting following error while trying to create build of react application

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file: 

./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/base/node.js:282 

Read more here:

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! atlas@2.0.0 staging: `env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the atlas@2.0.0 staging script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-09-24T06_00_59_644Z-debug.log
```